# What is the new "night-mode" map?

Tags: pokemon-go

Along with other features and bug fixes in the [0.57.2 for Android and 1.27.2 for iOS](http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/ver-update-021617), one is supposedly a new *night-mode* map

> Added new night-mode map and encounter music.

I am hearing the new music, but I have not a difference in the map prior to the update. What updates were made for this *night-mode* map?

Comment: [This article](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/pokemon-go-update/) makes it sound like it's just an option somewhere, but I've yet to find it.

Comment: Probably something similar to how Google maps switches at night time from white on black to black on white.

Comment: @Venemous Maybe that article is confusing it for the battery saver? At any rate, there's no new map. See my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a classic case of syntactic ambiguity. What the text really means is,

> Added new night-mode map [music] and encounter music.

As evidence, you'll notice that the map music is now different at night. There's no new map, just new music.